# Cannot get assign where working in Jekyll template

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I have built my website in Jekyll.

The data file is working fine when parsed elsewhere, but when I try to access a particular record using a `where` clause I get no result.

See the project at https://github.com/ohiweb/ohiweb.github.io

The troublesome page is under portfolio\betimca\index.html

### portfolio.yml

```
projects:
  - name: "betimca"
    title: "Betimca Subdivision Project"
    description: "These beautiful houses in Betimca feature classical elements with modern conveniences. Brick facades are crafted with accents tht stand out for maximum curb appeal. Gables with generous windows allow maximum light to upstairs rooms and add to their distinguished character."
    feature: "betimca_1a.jpg"
    media: "portfolio/betimca"
    images: [betimca_1a.jpg,betimca_1b.jpg,betimca_1c.jpg,betimca_2a.jpg,betimca_2b.jpg,betimca_3a.jpg,betimca_3b.jpg]
    tags: ["portfolio", "new construction", "residential", "subdivision"]
```

### index.html

```
{% assign project = site.data.portfolio.projects | where: "name", "betimca" %}
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-4">
            <header class="page-header">
                <h1>
                {{project.title}}
                </h1>
            </header>
            <p>{{project.description}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
            <img src="/media/{{project.media}}/{{project.feature}}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      {% for image in project.images %}
      <div class="col col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <span class="thumbnail">
          <img src="/media/{{project.media}}/{{image}}" alt="{{project.title}} {{image}}">
        </span>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% assign project = site.data.portfolio.projects | where: "name", "betimca" %}
```

This returns an array with one element.

If you want to get the element in project you can do :

```
{% assign project = site.data.portfolio.projects | where: "name", "betimca" | first %}
```

And now your page works.